# Which "size" file should I use to get the disk size?

Tags: disk

My disk is sda and I have these size files:

```
/sys/dev/block/8:0/size
/sys/class/block/sda/size
/sys/block/sda/size
```

Which one should I use? The first one is used by `lsblk`. Are there any differences?

Comment: Just use `lsblk -nbdo size /dev/sda` then you don't need to worry about what path under /sys to use or what unit the value may be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

```
ls -l /sys/dev/block/8:0 /sys/class/block/sda /sys/block/sda
```

You’ll see that all three point to the same directory.

There’s no difference between the files, other than their path.

Comment: I tried `ls -l` on the size files because I expected that. But it didn't work. Have to use `realpath` next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a path to a block device file such as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/disk/by-id/whatever`, `some/path/to/my/loop/device`, there are several options to get its size on Linux including:

1. open() the device and issue the `BLKGETSIZE64` `ioctl()`. That's what `blockdev --getsize64 path/to/block/device` does.
2. open() the device and issue the `BLKGETSIZE` `ioctl()` like `blockdev --getsz path/to/block/device` does, and multiply that by 512 (not what the `BLKSSZGET` ioctl() (as `blocksize --getss path/to/block/device`) returns).
3. open() the device, lseek() to the end which will return the current cursor position. For instance, in `zsh`:

   ```
   zmodload zsh/system
   { sysseek -w end 0 && print $(( systell(0) )); } < path/to/block/device
   ```
4. Assuming sysfs is mounted in `/sys`, find the corresponding path to the device file in there, read the `size` file in there and multiply by 512 (not the values in any of the `queue/*size` files in there).

For 1 to 3 above, you need at least read or write permission to the block device.

For 4, since the name of the block device file could be anything, the reliable way to identify the /sys path, and what `lsblk` does as you found out is to rely on the major and minor device numbers which you obtain by doing a `stat()` call on the path to the block device (for which you only need search access to the parent directory) and then use `/sys/dev/block/<major>:<minor>` which will be a symlink to the directory in the `/sys/devices` tree for the block device with `<major>` and `<minor>` as major/minor number.

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -sH s path/to/block/device &&
  [[ $s[mode] = b* ]] &&
  print $(( $(</sys/dev/block/$(( s[rdev] >> 8 )):$(( s[rdev] & 0xff ))/size) * 512 ))
```

Or you could just get `lsblk` to do it for you:

```
lsblk -nbdo size path/to/block/device
```

Answer (score 0):

`/sys/dev/block/8:0`, `/sys/class/block/sda` and `/sys/block/sda` are all just symlinks pointing to the same location so it doesn't matter which you use.

```
$ realpath /sys/dev/block/8:0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.1/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
$ realpath /sys/class/block/sda
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.1/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
$ realpath /sys/block/sda
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.1/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
```